# Ordinal indicators in URLs

Tags: url, seo

Imagine that you have the address of a bank office like this:

> Praça Almeida Junior , 35 3º Andar Anx I - São Paulo - SP

And the office's url it's generated automatically like this:

```
http://www.foo.com/banco-itau-praca-almeida-junior-35-3º-andar-anx-i-sao-paulo-sp
```

I would like to know if it's bad practice to use ordinal indicators in URLs, especially if it has a negative impact in SEO.